# Are Parameter Names Allowed in Function Pointer Deffinitions

Tags: c++, parameters, language-lawyer, function-pointers, named-parameters

So I just saw an example of a function pointer declaration that uses named parameters:

```
int (*func)(int a, int b) = &foo;
```

I'm assuming that this is well defined code cause it compiles and runs fine: https://ideone.com/C4mhsI

But I've never seen this before (probably because it increases the complexity of already difficult to parse function pointers.) Nonetheless, I'd like to see a statement that this is legal and not some crazy gcc extension. Can someone find me something?

Comment: @downvoter Any particular reason for the downvote? Or is this just the mandatory downvote for C++ questions?

Answer (score 6):

You can follow the grammar of a [*declarator*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.decl#5), which is a declaration without any type or decl specifiers.

> ```
> declarator:
>   ptr-declarator
>   [...]
>
> ptr-declarator:
>   noptr-declarator
>   ptr-operator ptr-declarator
>
> noptr-declarator:
>   [...]
>   noptr-declarator parameters-and-qualifiers
>   ( ptr-declarator )
>
> parameters-and-qualifiers:
>   ( parameter-declaration-clause ) [...]
>
> ptr-operator:
>   * attribute-specifier-seq[opt] cv-qualifier-seq[opt]
>   [...]
> ```

I removed every grammar rule that isn't needed, to be able to follow it more easily. I won't do it because it's a bit of a pain to write down, but at the end you will find that you have *parameters-and-qualifiers* that represents the parameters.

And if you do it for a function, you will see that it also ends with *parameters-and-qualifiers*. They use the same grammar, and there is nothing prohibiting this in the standard under [[decl.ptr]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ptr).

Comment: Nice, but to be honest production rules aren't the easiest to follow.

Comment: @PasserBy Yeah sometimes they can get very complicated very fast. So do you do want me to do it for this example? Or ist it ok?

Comment: I'm not sure of the best way, maybe say the resulting declarator has the form `( * declarator-id ) ( parameter-declaration, parameter-declaration )` and `parameter-declaration` is a `decl-specifier-seq` followed by a `declarator` or `abstract-declarator` in which there is no `declartor-id`?

Answer (score -1):

Just like you can you can specify the argument name in a function declaration:
`int funct(int a, int b);` you can in function pointers too `int (*func)(int a, int b)`. In both cases the names don't do anything, and in practice they are used as a documentation aid, for easier reading.

Comment: Note: this question is tagged [tag:language-lawyer].

Comment: You realize in the title of the question that I called these "named parameters" right? I knew what they were when I asked the question, thus I didn't ask: "What are these?" I asked: "Is it legal to name parameters in a function pointer definition?" You've made no attempt to answer that. Please either rectify this or delete this answer.

Comment: Declaring a function is valid in this way and putting a `*` in front of the declaration makes it a pointer. So pointer to function with syntax is valid as well.

Comment: @mdatsev OK? For what it's worth I also suspect it's legal. Unfortunately our opinions have less weight than the opinion of the gcc compiler which was presented in the question. I'm looking for an answer that can confirm gcc's stance. Ideally something more than our opinions.